# How can i change the speaker label in ibm watson speech to text api in android?

Tags: android, ibm-watson, speech-to-text

Good Day!

I need help in developing my android app. is this possible to change the default name of speaker label to a custom one like a person name. i would like to create like this conversation as I example..

```
 Jhon: Hi
 Marie: Hello
 Jhon: Good Day To you marie..
 Marie:......
```

Please help i need help if is this possible to change the default name of speaker label i need your help
i created like this

```
private RecognizeOptions getRecognizeOptions(InputStream captureStream) {
    return new RecognizeOptions.Builder()
            .audio(captureStream)
            .contentType(ContentType.OPUS.toString())
            .model("en-US_BroadbandModel")
            .interimResults(true)
            .inactivityTimeout(2000)
            .timestamps(true)
            .speakerLabels(true)
            .maxAlternatives(3)
            .smartFormatting(true)
            .timestamps(true)
            .wordConfidence(true)
            .build();
}
```

this is the method of .speakerLabels

```
public class SpeakerLabelsDiarization {
public static class RecoToken {
    private Double startTime;
    private Double endTime;
    private Long speaker;
    private String word;
    private Boolean spLabelIsFinal;


    /**
     * Instantiates a new reco token.
     *
     * @param speechTimestamp the speech timestamp
     */
    RecoToken(SpeechTimestamp speechTimestamp) {
        startTime = speechTimestamp.getStartTime();
        endTime = speechTimestamp.getEndTime();
        word = speechTimestamp.getWord();
    }

    /**
     * Instantiates a new reco token.
     *
     * @param speakerLabel the speaker label
     */
    RecoToken(SpeakerLabelsResult speakerLabel) {
        startTime = Double.valueOf(speakerLabel.getFrom());
        endTime = Double.valueOf(speakerLabel.getTo());
        speaker = speakerLabel.getSpeaker();
    }

    /**
     * Update from.
     *
     * @param speechTimestamp the speech timestamp
     */
    public void updateFrom(SpeechTimestamp speechTimestamp) {
        word = speechTimestamp.getWord();
    }

    /**
     * Update from.
     *
     * @param speakerLabel the speaker label
     */
    public void updateFrom(SpeakerLabelsResult speakerLabel) {
        speaker = speakerLabel.getSpeaker();
    }
}

/**
 * The Class Utterance.
 */
public static class Utterance {
    private Integer speaker;
    private String transcript = "";

    /**
     * Instantiates a new utterance.
     *
     * @param speaker    the speaker
     * @param transcript the transcript
     */
    public Utterance(final Integer speaker, final String transcript) {
        this.speaker = speaker;
        this.transcript = transcript;
    }
}

/**
 * The Class RecoTokens.
 */
public static class RecoTokens {

    private Map<Double, RecoToken> recoTokenMap;

    /**
     * Instantiates a new reco tokens.
     */
    public RecoTokens() {
        recoTokenMap = new LinkedHashMap<Double, RecoToken>();
    }

    /**
     * Adds the.
     *
     * @param speechResults the speech results
     */
    public void add(SpeechRecognitionResults speechResults) {
        if (speechResults.getResults() != null)
            for (int i = 0; i < speechResults.getResults().size(); i++) {
                SpeechRecognitionResult transcript = speechResults.getResults().get(i);
                if (transcript.isFinalResults()) {
                    SpeechRecognitionAlternative speechAlternative = transcript.getAlternatives().get(0);

                    for (int ts = 0; ts < speechAlternative.getTimestamps().size(); ts++) {
                        SpeechTimestamp speechTimestamp = speechAlternative.getTimestamps().get(ts);
                        add(speechTimestamp);
                    }
                }
            }
        if (speechResults.getSpeakerLabels() != null)
            for (int i = 0; i < speechResults.getSpeakerLabels().size(); i++) {
                add(speechResults.getSpeakerLabels().get(i));
            }

    }

    /**
     * Adds the.
     *
     * @param speechTimestamp the speech timestamp
     */
    public void add(SpeechTimestamp speechTimestamp) {
        RecoToken recoToken = recoTokenMap.get(speechTimestamp.getStartTime());
        if (recoToken == null) {
            recoToken = new RecoToken(speechTimestamp);
            recoTokenMap.put(speechTimestamp.getStartTime(), recoToken);
        } else {
            recoToken.updateFrom(speechTimestamp);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Adds the.
     *
     * @param speakerLabel the speaker label
     */
    public void add(SpeakerLabelsResult speakerLabel) {
        RecoToken recoToken = recoTokenMap.get(speakerLabel.getFrom());
        if (recoToken == null) {
            recoToken = new RecoToken(speakerLabel);
            recoTokenMap.put(Double.valueOf(speakerLabel.getFrom()), recoToken);
        } else {
            recoToken.updateFrom(speakerLabel);
        }

        if (speakerLabel.isFinalResults()) {
            markTokensBeforeAsFinal(speakerLabel.getFrom());
            report();
            cleanFinal();
        }
    }

    private void markTokensBeforeAsFinal(Float from) {
        Map<Double, RecoToken> recoTokenMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        for (RecoToken rt : recoTokenMap.values()) {
            if (rt.startTime <= from)
                rt.spLabelIsFinal = true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Report.
     */
    public void report() {
        List<Utterance> uttterances = new ArrayList<Utterance>();
        Utterance currentUtterance = new Utterance(0, "");

        for (RecoToken rt : recoTokenMap.values()) {
            if (currentUtterance.speaker != Math.toIntExact(rt.speaker)) {
                uttterances.add(currentUtterance);
                currentUtterance = new Utterance(Math.toIntExact(rt.speaker), "");
            }
            currentUtterance.transcript = currentUtterance.transcript + rt.word + " ";
        }
        uttterances.add(currentUtterance);

        String result = GsonSingleton.getGson().toJson(uttterances);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    private void cleanFinal() {
        Set<Map.Entry<Double, RecoToken>> set = recoTokenMap.entrySet();
        for (Map.Entry<Double, RecoToken> e : set) {
            if (e.getValue().spLabelIsFinal) {
                recoTokenMap.remove(e.getKey());
            }
        }
    }

}


private static CountDownLatch lock = new CountDownLatch(1);
```

}

the output in that is like this`

```
 speaker 0: Hi
 speaker 1: Hello
 speaker 0: Good Day To you marie..
 speaker 1:......
```

and i would like to output like this

```
 Jhon: Hi
 Marie: Hello
 Jhon: Good Day To you marie..
 Marie:......
```

my question is. Is this possible to create like that in ibm watspon speech to text api because i read in their documentation their are not mentioning on how to change the labels i just want to clarify it if is this possible

Comment: can you elaborate a little bit? how did you create that label?

Comment: i am using the default method in ibm watson api sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in the API nor the documentation to suggest that it is possible to modify the labels in the output using the service itself. https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/speech-to-text/output.html#speaker_labels